# Tools needed to perform groupset overhaul

Tags: tools, upgrades

I'm looking at buying the new Shimano 105 5800 equipment for my bike. It is a 2010 Specialized Allez (Sport Triple) and still has its basic Sora components that it came with. I asked my local bike shop how much it would cost to buy & fit (6400 sek, ~€700 of which roughly $50 was the labour). Looking online, Wiggle sells the groupset at ~€400, and Chainreactioncycles at ~€450. If I can equip myself with the right tools for significantly less than the €300 saving it makes sense for me to DIY.

**My questions:**

What tools will I **need** to buy to be able to completely overhaul?

What other tools are **recommended** to make it easier? (e.g. cable crimpers are better than regular pliers..)

Comment: In one of your other questions you mention that you have Zinn. It is a good choice of manual and IIRC he lists the tools that are (a) useful in general and (b) required for a specific task. I suggest you go read that and come back if you have any problems understanding it.

Comment: Either what PeteH says above or jump on Park Tools website and familiarise yourself. Identify the parts you have and what tools you need. The difficulty you will find is that there are many different standards. For example removing a Sora crankset requires a crank puller and the bottom bracket a cartridge tool. Installing a 105 bottom bracket requires a threaded external tool, installing the crankset needs a hex wrench. It'll still be cheaper to buy tools but many you'll only use once (go cheap) and others a lot in the future (buy quality). You can also on sell 2nd hand tools (and buy them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A road groupset usually consists of a number of parts.

There are not many tools, and they are generally not that expensive.

With all the resources out there (youtube, sheldon brown website, etc) and basic mechanical aptitude it isn't a difficult task.

You need basic hand/bike tools, (hammer, metric allen keys/drivers, screwdrivers, pliers, socket set, torque wrench, etc)

In terms of specific tools for those components:

- Bottom Bracket (BB)

> If Pressfit:
>    **A BB press, a BB punch/remover.**
>
> If Threaded: **A BB Wrench**

- Cassette : **Chain Whip, Cassette lockring socket tool.**
- Chain : **Chain breaker, Chain tool or missing link pliers depending on chain**
- Brakes
- Crankset : **Pedal wrench or allen keys depending on the pedals.**

> Modern Shimano specific (like the 105 group): **Hollowtech II crank arm installation tool**
>
> Front derailleur
>
> Rear derailleur
>
> STI levers (Shifters/Brakes)
>
> You will probably need to replace the cables, so a *cable puller* might come in handy.

An optional extra that would come in handy and for future work on the bike would be a *bike workshop stand* I spent 100$ on mine and it has been excellent for regular maintenance and upgrading parts.

Comment: +1 A stand is essential. FYI, you will need to replace (or remove and reuse) cables if replacing shifters as the cable stop is at the shifter end.

Comment: Asking the bike shop to remove the existing crankset and bottom bracket would probably be cost effective and save you having to buy 2 tools that you are unlikely to ever use again (as is my personal experience).

Comment: Cable cutters are an under rated tool that save a lot of headaches. Side cutters work for cables but not as good or as easy.

Comment: A cheap stand and an expensive pair of cutters are the best tools I ever bought. Those two things alone make life so much more bearable in the workshop.